# Error: Command failed with exit code 3221225781: ... \prisma\query-engine-windows.exe cli get-config --ignoreEnvVarErrors

Tags: prisma-graphql

I had an issue about [Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again], so I put postinstall : “prisma generate” on script of package.json. But the issue still happens.
I also installed @prisma/client module using npm.
How can I solve this problem?
I’m using window 10.

Comment: do you have `c++ redistributable` on your computer ?

Comment: also could you share your `prisma.schema`

Comment: @SefaUn thanks I solved this !! 
 I download c++ redistributable because I don't have c++ redistributable